# user.is_authenticated DetailView is coming as True

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-authentication, django-users, django-3.0

I have a Users model and exposing the user details via DetailView.

In the template navbar section, currently use is_authenticated to render url as below.

`if {% user.is_authenticated %} my_account {% else %} login_url`

Now I am exposing the User details via DetailView like

````
// views.py
class ProfileView(DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'account/user_profile.html'

// account/user_profile.html

shows the links(```my_account``` or ```login_url```) and user details viz. username,email & location(via separate ProfileModel)


// models.py
import django.contrib.auth.models import User

def Profile(models.Model)
    user = models.OnetoOneField(User)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
````

but this results in showing `my_account` url on user_profile.html page which I understand is due to the auth context `user= self.request.user`

To change this behaviour I tried changing the DetailView as follows.

```
class ProfileView(DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'account/user_profile.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            print("context:",context['user'].is_authenticated)
            return context    
        else:
            context['user'] = None
            return context
```

Is this a recommended way or there are other recommendations,

Comment: you are working with you profile model soo the model should be profile not user.

Comment: @ngawang13 - ok, so fetching userdetails via the profile to user relationship, just out of curiosity, how would that work, if the Profile model was an AbstractModel instead of having a separate Profile model?